# multiprocessing.Pool not running on last element of iterable

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run a function `func` which takes in a list of indices as argument and process the data.

```
def func(rng):
    **some processing**
    write_csv_to_disk(processed_data[rng],mode="a")


import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.map(func,list_of_lists_of_indices)
pool.close()
```

The function saves partial `DataFrame[indices]`  processed in parallel onto a file in `append` mode. The code runs well for all the sub-lists of `list_of_lists_of_indices`, except the last list. The data against the indices in the last list is not saved to my file and the pool is closed.

```
list_of_lists_of_indices = [[0,1,2,3,4,.....,99999],[100000,100001,100002,100003,100004,......,199999],.....,[10000000,10000001,...,100000895]]
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.map(func,iterable = list_of_lists_of_indices)
pool.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you're not saying what `write_csv_to_disk` does, but there seem to be a few possible issues here:

1. you have multiple processes writing to the same file at the same time and that really can't go well unless you're taking specific steps (e.g. lockfile) to avoid them overwriting one another
2. the symptoms you're explaining look a lot like you're not properly closing your file objects, relying on the garbage collector to do that and close your buffers, except on the last iteration it's possible that e.g. the worker dies before the GC running, therefore the file is not closed and its buffer is not flushed to disk
3. also while the *results* of a `Pool.map` are in-order (at great expense) *there's no guarantee as to what order they'll execute in*. Since it's the workers doing the writing to disk, there is no reason for these to be ordered. I don't even see why you're using `map`, the entire point of map is to return computation results, which you're not doing here

   You should not be using Pool.map, and you should not be "saving to a file in append mode".

Also note that `Pool.close` means you're not going to give new work to the pool, *it doesn't wait for the workers to be done*. Now in theory that should not matter if you're only using sync methods, however in this case and given (2) that might be a problem: when the parent process exits the Pool probably gets garbage-collected which means *it hard-shuts down pool workers*.

Comment: `Pool.join()` could be used  to wait for the all the worker processes to exit.

Comment: Yes but depending how eagerly the workers themselves exit I don't know that all the cleanup is guaranteed to run, which is my fear here. Not to mention there's obviously a *ton* of code we're not given which could misbehave in all sorts of ways. Given the OP is apparently writing to a single file from 4 different processes we're not exactly off to a good start.

Comment: @Masklinn: Thanks for the explanation. The function `func` takes a huge DataFrame already in memory, picks up a `subset` as determined by the `rng`parameter, processes the data and then finally writes the processed `dataframe` to a file in `append` mode. I agree that there could be multiple processes trying to write the data to the file simultaneously. What do you suggest I should to do to avoid this situation? I can write output of every iteration to a new file but then that will create a large number of files. Order in which data is saved does not matter to me. If not `Pool.map()` then what?

Comment: @tushaR apply / apply_async with a dedicated worker synchronising access to the output, or you could use imap / imap_unordered and have the "main process" do the actual writing of the output to a file (that's more traffic and possibly costlier but also simpler than needing an additional synchronisation process). Regardless you should definitely join() your pool after closing it: if the parent process exits and collects the pool, it'll hard-shutdown pool workers, if one of them has not flushed its buffer yet (we still don't know how you manage your file) it will lose data.

Comment: @Masklinn: If I got you correct, the "main process" that you referred in your comment above is the function `func` and `write_csv_to_disk` is a part of it.

Comment: the "main process" would be what calls pool.map. By having `func` return the processed results instead of trying to write them to disk, the caller can handle the writing safely (as there's only one process accessing the output).